# can't change file permissions of key file

Tags: ssh, chmod

I have a .pem file. The normal chmod [4/6]00 [key_name_here].pem command doesn't work. The permissions are stubbornly stuck at 444 or 644.

Comment: How about try to change it with `sudo chmod ....`?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't change anything. Also if I try to do this via the GUI, the settings immediately revert.

Comment: Is the key on a "special" file system such as NTFS or VFAT ? Network mounted (nfs, samba)? Is the file system mounted ro ?

Comment: It's on a usb drive in fat 32 format

Comment: fat32 does not support permissions. Ownership and permissions are set at the time of mounting. If you need linux permissions use a linux file system ;)

Comment: good to know, bodhi.zazen!

Comment: See the link I just gave you for how to set ownership and permissions when you mount the partition.

Comment: Thx. I might just change the location of the file. Seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try changing the ownership first and then try to manipulate the `chmod`

How about `sudo chown [yourusername] file.pem` and then `chmod`